# use subprocess.Popen to run a unix tool that requires multiple input redirects

Tags: python, shell, unix

I'd like to execute this series of commands from within a python program.

```
wc -l <(comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt))
```

I've been successful with the following:

```
sort_a = Popen("sort file1.txt", shell=False, stdout=PIPE)
count = Popen(["wc", "-l"], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=sort_a.stdin)
```

What I haven't been able to figure out his how to redirect multiple stdouts to the stdin of comm -12.

I thought perhaps:

```
compare = Popen(["comm", "-12"], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=[sort_a.stdin, sort_b.stdin])
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let’s look at how the shell’s `<(command)` command substitution works. The
command is started with the output pointing to a newly created pipe. Then the
pipe is passed on the command line as a *filename* to the outer command.

For example:

```
$ echo wc -w <(date)
wc -l /dev/fd/63
```

Shows that the shell starts `date` with output to a pipe, and then passes the
pseudofile `/dev/fd/63` referring to the new pipe at file descriptor 63 as the actual command line argument.

---

To get the same behaviour in Python, we can implement the same thing:

```
from subprocess import *

date = Popen(['date'], stdout=PIPE)
Popen(["wc", "-w", "/dev/fd/%d" % date.stdout.fileno()])
```

print

```
6 /dev/fd/3
```

---

You could write a class to make it easier to do. This uses a [`with` statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and temporarily keeps references to each spawned process, because otherwise the pipes would get closed when the process objects got garbage-collected.

```
from subprocess import *

class CommandSubstituter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._procs = []

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        pass

    def subst(self, *args, **kwargs):
        proc = Popen(*args, stdout=PIPE, **kwargs)
        self._procs.append(proc)
        return "/dev/fd/%d" % proc.stdout.fileno()

with CommandSubstituter() as c:
    Popen(['wc', '-l',
           c.subst(['comm', '-12',
                    c.subst(['sort', 'file1.txt']),
                    c.subst(['sort', 'file2.txt'])])])
```